# How to pass "--command" to "kubectl run" that also uses "--overrides"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I noticed a strange behavior while experimenting with `kubectl run` :

- When the command to be executed is passed as option flag `--command -- /bin/sh -c "ls -lah"` > **OK**

  ```
  kubectl run nodejs --image=node:lts-alpine \
    --restart=Never --quiet -i --rm \
    --command -- /bin/sh -c "ls -lah"
  ```
- When command to be executed is passed in `--overrides` with `"command": [ "ls", "-lah" ]` > **OK**

  ```
  kubectl run nodejs --image=node:lts-alpine \
    --restart=Never \
    --overrides='
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "nodejs"
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "host-volume",
            "hostPath": {
              "path": "/home/dferlay/Sources/df-sdc/web/themes/custom/"
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "nodejs",
            "image": "busybox",
            "command": [
              "ls",
              "-lah"
            ],
            "workingDir": "/app",
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "host-volume",
                "mountPath": "/app"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "FallbackToLogsOnError",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Never",
        "securityContext": {
          "runAsUser": 1000,
          "runAsGroup": 1000
        }
      }
    }
    ' \
    --quiet -i --rm
  ```
- When the command to be executed is passed as option flag `--command -- /bin/sh -c "ls -lah"` and `--overrides` is used for something else (volume for instance) > **KO**

  ```
  kubectl run nodejs --image=node:lts-alpine --restart=Never \
    --overrides='
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "nodejs"
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "host-volume",
            "hostPath": {
              "path": "/home/dferlay/Sources/df-sdc/web/themes/custom/"
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "nodejs",
            "image": "busybox",
            "workingDir": "/app",
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "host-volume",
                "mountPath": "/app"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "FallbackToLogsOnError",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Never",
        "securityContext": {
          "runAsUser": 1000,
          "runAsGroup": 1000
        }
      }
    }
    ' \
    --quiet -i --rm --command -- /bin/sh -c "ls -lah"
  ```

So it looks like using `--overrides` prevents `--command` to be used.

However, I precisely need to use `--command` to bypass the array format expected by `--overrides` (ie. `"command": [ "ls", "-lah" ]`) because in my use case the command is a placeholder and cannot be known in advance.

- How can I do that ? Is there something I'm missing ?

FYI: `kubectl version=v1.23.1+k3s2`

Comment: The problem here is that you're overring the value of `spec.containers`, so you're *replacing* the content generated by the command line parameters. Can you tell us more about your use case? Maybe there's another way to get what you want.

Comment: Is there any way to merge the `spec.containers` override with the rest of the command ? I tried new flag `--override-type` added in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105140 without success

Comment: To answer your question @larsks, my current usecase is to replace is to replace `docker run` commands by `kubectl run` here https://github.com/skilld-labs/skilld-docker-container/blob/8a8f520533abdaaf97aca4f2b45eec87a36b45bc/scripts/makefile/front.mk#L3-L30

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the array format by using the `args` field:

```
"command": [
 "sh",
 "-c"
],
"args": [ "pwd && id && node YOUR_COMMAND" ]
```